# ASP MVC - byte[] to Image

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, arrays

I have an issue with my ASP MVC site. I'm trying to convert `byte[]` to image "on the fly" inside cshtml file. Here is the code sample:

```
<div class="col-md-6 portfolio-item">
    <table>
        @foreach (var item in new Projek2.Models.DatabaseEntities().Photos)
        {
              <tr>
                <td>
                    @using (var ms = new MemoryStream(item.Photo1))
                    {
                        <img src=@System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms)/>
                    }
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FileName)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

It throws an error (`InvalidOperation` as far as I remember) during `FromStream()` conversion or shows only little placeholders instead of images (like unloaded image).

Anyone knows the trick to convert `byte[]` to valid cshtml image?

Comment: Using a stream will not work. you could convert it to a data url which holds a base 64 string representation of the image source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following assumptions

- `item.Photo1` is byte[]
- `item` has a mime property that contains photo's mime type like `image/png` or `image/jpeg`, etc.. Other wise you can derive mime type from file name assuming that name contains file extension.

You can create a [Data URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) and embed it as the source (src) of the image.

```
<div class="col-md-6 portfolio-item">
    <table>
        @foreach (var item in new Projek2.Models.DatabaseEntities().Photos)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="@System.String.Format("data:{0};base64,{1}",item.Mime,Convert.ToBase64String(item.Photo1))"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FileName)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

Do note that from my assumption if the item does not store the image type then you can create a helper method to derive the type from the image file name given it contains the file extension of the image. using a format like `image\{file extension}`